# Bootstrap 3 row background color extend 100% of the window width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I have a row in **bootstrap 3** have a background color that extends the entire 100% width, without having the content use `container-fluid`? See the following example. Notice, that the grey background does not extend 100% of the window width. I'd like to keep the content contained within container, just have the background grey of the **foo** blocks.

http://www.bootply.com/iWA6r5vfdJ

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking, maybe, something like http://www.bootply.com/eFqgNebw9B ?

Comment: Awesome, I'll plug it as an answer so we can close this!

Answer (score 9):

Looks like if you work with multiple `.containers`, you can achieve what you're looking for by adding `.bg-grey` around the container, instead of on the `.row`.

http://www.bootply.com/eFqgNebw9B